# Why np.array converts to array a list and its elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm newbie with Python and there is something that I don't understand in this code:

```
import numpy as np

a_list = []
sub_list = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

a_list.append(sub_list)

print(type(a_list))
print(type(a_list[0]))
print(type(sub_list))

array = np.array(a_list)

print(type(array))
print(type(array[0]))
print(type(sub_list))
print(array[0])
```

When I run it, I get this output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'list'>
['apple' 'banana' 'cherry']
```

Why `type(array[0])` is also `numpy.ndarray`? Shouldn't it be a list?

Comment: An array of lists is pretty much pointless in numpy. It makes sense that a nested structure will simply become a nested array. Why do you want to keep them as lists?

Comment: @roganjosh I don't want to keep it as a list. I thought that `np.darray` will convert to numpy array only the variable, not the variable and its contents.

Comment: I'd wager that this is purely for convenience because I can't think of a case where I wouldn't _want_ this behaviour. That said, you should be more concerned about the `dtype` that it gets converted to, because that can have significant impacts on how the resultant array will behave (e.g. `object` is not "good news" and will suffer in efficiency if you try to apply numpy operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [36]:  
    ...: a_list = [] 
    ...: sub_list = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"] 
    ...:  
    ...: a_list.append(sub_list)                                                
In [37]: arr = np.array(a_list)                                                 
In [38]: a_list                                                                 
Out[38]: [['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']]
In [39]: arr                                                                    
Out[39]: array([['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']], dtype='<U6')
In [40]: arr[0]                                                                 
Out[40]: array(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'], dtype='<U6')
In [41]: arr.shape                                                              
Out[41]: (1, 3)
```

`np.array` tries to make a multidimensional array from its inputs.  `a_list` is a nested list, from which it can make a 2d array.  `arr[0]` is a 1d array, selected from `arr`.

`arr` is not an array of lists.  It's an array of string elements.

It is possible to make an array that contains lists:

```
In [42]: arr1 = np.empty(1, object)                                             
In [43]: arr1                                                                   
Out[43]: array([None], dtype=object)
In [44]: arr1[0]=sub_list                                                       
In [45]: arr1                                                                   
Out[45]: array([list(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'])], dtype=object)
In [46]: arr1[0]                                                                
Out[46]: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

but for most purposes this is little better than a list, `a_list`, and in some ways worse (you can't for example `.append` to it).

A classic case of making a 2d array from nested lists:

```
In [47]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])                                            
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [48]: _.shape                                                                
Out[48]: (2, 3)
```

Math operations on this pure numeric array are considerably faster than if it is an object dtype array containing lists.  Python already has nestable lists.